# Accessing data before sending it to server with Form.Request?

Tags: javascript, forms, mootools

Is there a way to access the whole data array/object (which contains all the data form input fields etc) before sending it to the server with Form.Request? I know there is the extraData option which allows you to pass in other data, but I would like to access the actual form data and to some manipulation with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Before* being sent to the server? I'm not entirely sure, the `send` method attached to `Form.Request` sends in the form itself, and the data, but this is probably after the request has already been fired off.

I tend not to use `Form.Request`, precisely because I have to do these form manipulations and such.

Instead of using a `Form.Request` Class, I simply iterate through the form's inputs as necessary.

e.g.

```
<form id="foobar">
    <input type="text" id="lorem" />
    <select id="ipsum">
        <option>...
    </select>
</form>
<script>
    var formValues = document.id('foobar').getElements('input, select');
</script>
```